# Requesting passing data with Requests module

Tags: python, python-2.7

i'm trying to do an request to my university web page to retrieve my grade .
the page who have my grade need to log in  in ""http://www4.uva.br/UniversusNet/Seguro/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fUniversusNet%2fNotasFaltasTotais.aspx" first after that 
the page reddirect me to the grade.

i want to print my grade on app that i making.
so far i made this code to print the page but when i execute the return is error 407 : proxy authentication
i want to now what i missing....

```
from requests import *

payload = {'__EVENTTARGET':'','__EVENTARGUMENT':'','__VIEWSTATE':'/wEPDwULLTE4NzU1ODgxNTkPZBYCZg9kFgICAw9kFgICCQ9kFgICAQ9kFgICAQ9kFgICAQ8QZGQWAGQYAQU2Y3RsMDAkRm9ybXVsYXJpb0NvbnRlbnRQbGFjZUhvbGRlciRFc3RhZG9UZWxhTXVsdGlWaWV3Dw9kZmT14eU493cBliuPCSv6TJQbGDKjrA=='
                  ,'__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR':'7C9DFC57'
                  ,'ctl00$FormularioContentPlaceHolder$UsuarioTextBox':"@@@@@"
                  ,"ctl00$FormularioContentPlaceHolder$SenhaTextBox":"@@@@@"
                  ,'ctl00$FormularioContentPlaceHolder$EntrarButton':'Entrar'}

requestheaders = {
    'Accept'                    : 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding'           : 'gzip,deflate',
    'Accept-Language'           : 'pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
    'Cache-Control'             : 'max-age=0',
    'Proxy-Connection'          : 'keep-alive',
    'Content-Type'              : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Host'                      : 'www4.uva.br',
    'Origin'                    : 'http://www4.uva.br',
    'Cookie'                    : '',
    'Pragma'                    : 'no-cache',
    'Referer'                   : 'https://web.iress.com.au/html/LogonForm.aspx',   
    'User-Agent'                : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,  like Gecko) Chrome/##ADRESSS AS ABOVE## Safari/537.36'

    }

with session() as sesh:

    LOGINURL = 'http://www4.uva.br/UniversusNet/Seguro/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fUniversusNet%2fNotasFaltasTotais.aspx'
    sesh.get(LOGINURL,proxies={"http":"xxxxxxx:xxxx"},auth=("xxxxxxx","xxxxxxxx")) #Get request to get the session ID cookie
##    sessionID = sesh.cookies['ASP.NET_SessionId'] #Grab session ID value
##    sessionIDname = 'ASP.NET_SessionId='
##    sessionIDheader = str(sessionIDname + sessionID) #Prepare session ID header
##    requestheaders['Cookie'] = sessionIDheader # Add session ID header to requestheaders dictionary


    response = sesh.post('http://www4.uva.br/UniversusNet/Seguro/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fUniversusNet%2fNotasFaltasTotais.aspx', data=payload,  headers=requestheaders)

    print(response.headers)
    print(response.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the proxy information to the session directly (something like):

```py
from requests.auth import HTTPProxyAuth


sesh.proxies = {
    "http": "http://www4.uva.br:8080",  # MAKE SURE THE DATA IS CORRECT !!!
}
sesh.auth = HTTPProxyAuth("user", "pwd")

sesh.get(LOGINURL)
```

Comment: Hmm, how do you authenticate from a web browser (where it works)? Try copying those settings in your code, and add the arguments back: **proxies** will be a dictionary in form of _{"http": "proxy_host:proxy_port"}_ or maybe _https_ (if your proxy server is secured), while **auth** will be a tuple _("user", "password")_.